# Merge multiple glossaries types in one single glossary

Tags: glossaries

I would like to "merge" two glossaries in a single `\printglossary` or something equivalent (see MWE).

Additional requirements:

1. enable sorting by e.g. name across the glossaries

Is there a way to do so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}           

\newglossary[sog]{symbol}{soi}{soo}{Symbols}
\newglossary[fog]{operator}{foi}{foo}{Operators}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{typeAentry1}{%
    type=symbol,
    name={A1},
    description={none}
}

\newglossaryentry{typeBentry1}{%
    type=operator,
    name={B1},
    description={none}
}

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall

    % single separated glossaries
    \printglossary[title=Symbols,type={symbol}]
    \printglossary[title=Operators,type={operator}]

    %what i would like to do
    %\printglossary[title=Symbols and Operators,type={symbols LOGICAL OR operator}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't merging, but moving from one glossary to another one with `\glsmoveentry{label}{target glossary}`.

Since there is more than one entry (most likely) one could use the

```
\forallglsentries[operator]{\localfoo}{\glsmoveentry{\localfoo}{symbol}}
```

command, to move all entries from, say, `operator` to `symbol`. The `\localfoo` is an 'arbitrary' command sequence and expands to the current gls label of the entry, e.g. `\typeBentry1` in the current setup.

The use case is in my point of view where the entries are for different glossaries are stored in an individual file for each glossary and are loaded with `\loadglsentries`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}           

\newglossary[sog]{symbol}{soi}{soo}{Symbols}
\newglossary[fog]{operator}{foi}{foo}{Operators}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{typeAentry1}{%
    type=symbol,
    name={A1},
    description={Is a symbol}
}

\newglossaryentry{typeBentry1}{%
    type=operator,
    name={B1},
    description={comes from Operator}
}


\begin{document}

\def\localfoo{}
\forallglsentries[operator]{\localfoo}{\glsmoveentry{\localfoo}{symbol}}


\gls{typeBentry1} and \gls{typeAentry1}


    % single separated glossaries
    \printglossary[title=Symbols,type={symbol}]
    %\printglossary[title=Operators,type={operator}]

    %what i would like to do
    %\printglossary[title=Symbols and Operators,type={symbols LOGICAL OR operator}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's one backdraw: Nothing is moved if the the glslabel is not used so far.

Comment: If you were to surround your `\forallglsentries` loop with `\glsaddall` and `\glsresetall` to trick the migration into being complete, would that work?  Or would it have the undesired consequence of including it in the new glossary even if it hadn't been used?

Comment: @EngBIRD: I am unsure. I don't think this will work, but perhaps, I am not seeing the possibilities here ;-)

Comment: @EngBIRD @Christian Hupfer : the `\glsaddall' approach does not work for me on trying out, but the restrictions of the given solution are acceptable in my usecase. Thx

Comment: @4reigner: I know, that's why I used `\gls` explicitly. I try to figure out why this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to get `makeindex` to merge them. For example, suppose the following document is called `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}           

\newglossary[sog]{symbol}{soi}{soo}{Symbols}
\newglossary[fog]{operator}{foi}{foo}{Operators}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{typeAentry1}{%
    type=symbol,
    name={A1},
    description={none}
}

\newglossaryentry{typeBentry1}{%
    type=operator,
    name={B1},
    description={none}
}

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall

    \printglossary[title=Symbols and Operators,type=symbol]
\end{document}
```

Then you can merge the `operator` glossary into the `symbol` glossary using:

```
pdflatex test
makeindex -s test.ist -t test.sog -o test.soi test.soo test.foo
pdflatex test
```

(or replace `pdflatex` with `latex` or `xelatex`, as appropriate). This produces:

[image: image of merged glossary]